# HardFault with a Macro on a if or while statement in C language

Tags: c, crash, embedded, stm32

I have the following macro that i use for reading a single bit in a register on my STM32F091:

```
#define GET_BIT(reg, pos)          (((reg)>>(pos))&0x00000001u)
```

I have to use this macro with these two parameters:

```
#define FLASH_KEYR                 (*((u32_t *)(0x40022004u)))
#define BSY_FLASH_SR_POS           (0u)
```

I don't have any problem using this Macro for evaluating a single variable like:

```
uint32_t value = GET_BIT(FLASH_SR, BSY_FLASH_SR_POS);
```

But, using this macro on a conditional statement like this:

```
    while (GET_BIT(FLASH_SR, BSY_FLASH_SR_POS) == 1u);
```

The micro goes into the ISR for the HardFault.

...Why?

Comment: What is FLASH_SR - ie show definition (do not explain what SR register does). Waht is REGISTER_ADDRESS

Comment: why `0x00000001u` instead of simple `1`

Comment: @Toad __ - `GET_BIT(((REGISTER_ADDRESS)>>(FIELD_POSITION))&0x00000001u)` is not a valid invocation of the 2-argument macro `GET_BIT(reg, pos)`.

Comment: The invocation you say works, is not the same as the in you say breaks, so it is likely that it is nothing to do with if or while but rather the parameters. It is in any event a terrible idea. Rather than have a bit position macro, use a bit mask macro (probably already defined in the chip header) and test the bit directly, or use the bitband address to read the bit directly.

Comment: Now, did you want to shift the register address or the register value? What you are actually doing and whether it makes sense semantically will depend on the definition of FLASH_SR. Macros are bad because they obfuscate the semantics of the code. To debug one you have to consider the _full_ expansion and whether it is both syntactically and in this case semantically correct.

Comment: Thank you all, i've modified the second code paragraph and i will add the define of the 2 defines used as parameters, i think now it's more clear to understand

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are re-inventing the wheel, and it came out wrong.

Rather than help you to re-invent another new wheel, here is the existing wheel that ST already made for you:

```
#include "stm32f0xx.h"

...

while ((FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY) != 0);
```

Comment: No, i'm not re-inventing the wheel cause I can't use the ST library in this safety-critical project

Comment: I've worked extensively in IEC-62304 medical device software and motor vehicle/military projects.  Any auditor with half a brain cell would trust the device register definition headers from the hardware manufacturer, that are used in thousands of projects much more than anything you could ever write.  The same doesn't apply to the STL or HAL libraries, but you should unquestionably use the headers.  This is proved correct by the fact that you cannot get it to work and are asking random strangers on the internet for help on something supposed to be safety critical.

Comment: To be specific about the SMT32 thing: those header defines the registers as structures and ANSI-C does not define the memory footprint of such constructs, it's better not to use them generally.
In general: i'm just writing some peripheral drivers, nothing complicated. Further more, you can forget i'm on STM32, this question is generic ("why this code is not working").

Comment: You aren't using "any compiler in general".  You are using an ARM EABI compliant compiler, or you should be.  Put a reference to the ARM EABI standard in your compiler validation documentation package, and then you can rely on structure packing being formally defined.  Look at ISO14971 risk management for medical devices (or equivalent on your industry).  The risk of reinventing the wheel is always higher than doing it the standard way and giving proper documentation of why the standard way is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on reinventing the wheel then the reason it doesn't work in a loop is because you missed out volatile from the pointer cast.

My other answer is still the correct professional one (especially in a safety critical setting) but it sounds from the comments like this is the answer you would prefer to accept.